# Focus menu bar Help menu Search field in different keyboard layouts

Tags: keyboard, menu-bar, keybindings, dvorak, macos

In the default U.S. QWERTY keyboard layout, pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> (aka <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>?</kbd>) opens the Help menu item and focuses the Search field.

Pressing the keyboard shortcut and then typing allows you to easily search through the many menu bar commands.

[image: QWERTY menu]

However, in the Dvorak keyboard layout, pressing the same keyboard shortcut instead directly opens the "App Help" user guide in a new window. This is indicated by the "<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>?</kbd>" keyboard shortcut appearing in the submenu item for the user guide.

In Dvorak, I am *not* given a chance to type. Pressing the keyboard shortcut only opens the mostly-useless help documents in a new window. The Search field is not focused. I can't search the menu bar items.

[image: Dvorak menu]

---

This setting seems to be controlled by:

`System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts > All Applications > Show Help menu`

In QWERTY, the Search field is focused when this setting is toggled on; the Help window is opened when toggled off. The keyboard shortcut is hidden or shown in the menu respectively.

[image: 'Show Help menu' keyboard shortcut]

In Dvorak, this setting seemingly has no effect. Both toggle states open the Help window.

Do any other keyboard layouts have this problem?

Is there any way to set a keyboard shortcut to focus the Help menu's Search bar in Dvorak?

Comment: Have you tried the input source named "Dvorak Qwerty"?

Comment: @TomGewecke The `Dvorak - QWERTY ⌘` input method **does** trigger the menu, via the the QWERTY key positions. I however cannot use that input method due to preferring the Dvorak shortcut positions.